# iPhone development tools and languages

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to build an iPhone application with very rich user interface. I learnt Obj-C. I wanted to know what all technologies/languages I need to know further for developing such kind of apps.
What are the recent technologies used to develop iphone apps?

Please let me know.

Thanks,
AE

Comment: @user2526590- Google.com

Comment: It depends on the type & scope of your app. Before asking a question such as this (and subsequently getting flamed by particular folks) I would suggest pinning down your use case and hitting up Google first. If you end up with a specific development question this is the place to be. (@rmaddy - good call - thx)

Answer (score 3):

**I have done Google for you, really very tough task to do it**

Start with
video tuorials from youtube of standford university:-

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Qn-JUtQrsM

Then you can start with

https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/gettingstarted/

http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/category/tutorials/iphone/

http://iphonelearning.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/beginning-iphone-development/

Comment: first give Apple docs,thats the first book or page for any new people in ios

Answer (score 2):

You can read apple docs,its very simple and good 
[How to develop iphone app](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html)

**Tools**

Xcode provides tools to manage your entire development workflow—from creating your app and designing your user interface, to testing, optimizing, and shipping your app to the App Store. You can customize Xcode to suit your style of working, keeping you focused on the task at hand.

**Languages**

Objective-C is an elegant object-oriented language that powers all iOS apps. You write Objective-C code to create your app, and you need to understand this language in order to use most application frameworks. Although you can use other languages for development, you can’t build an iOS app without Objective-C.(But we can use Apache cordova(phonegap) for  developing non native app )

Comment: I believe there are other native compilers.  [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com) for example.

Comment: In my view ,Xcode is the best..

Comment: I was referring to your statement, *"you can’t build an iOS app without Objective-C"*

Comment: Its not my statement ,its by apple c my link in answer.you can see apple itself says like that

Comment: Ah you're right they *do* say that.  In that case, I disagree with Apple's statement :)

Comment: may be the are talking about the best

Comment: Most likely they're talking about the only method they promote as well as support..  Or, that page was written back in the early days of iOS development when it was probably true.  Or, whoever wrote it lives in an Apple bubble, drinks the Apple KoolAid and isn't aware of any other technologies.

Comment: i like your website KitchenPC.com